# Meteor - Publish all Users to Client just for admin

Tags: mongodb, templates, meteor

I have the folowing problem with Meteor:
I have one admin, that needs to see all registered users.
But all the other users shouldn't have the ability to see the other users.
Therefore I published the following code on the serverside

```
Meteor.publish("adminUsers", function(){

   var result; 
   if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ["admin"]))
   {
        result = Meteor.users.find();
   }
   //console.log(result);
   return result;
});
```

On client side I subscribe to this with

```
Meteor.subscribe("adminUsers");
```

And do

```
AllUsers = new Meteor.Collection("adminUsers");
```

Now I want to get all the Users in a Template with this code:

```
Template.adminUserverwaltung.AllUsers = function(){
console.log(AllUsers.find());
return AllUsers.find();
}
```

and show the result in the template with this code:

```
    <template name="adminUserverwaltung">
  {{#each AllUsers}}
    {{this.username}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

But unfortunately it is not working... Can anyone help me maybe?

Answer (score 5):

When you subscribe to the collection the subscription name is `adminUsers` but the users collection is still `Meteor.users` which is already defined.

So just alter it to use that instead

```
Template.adminUserverwaltung.AllUsers = function(){
    return Meteor.users.find();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there... This answer uses the meteor-roles package as the OP posed in the question.

```
Meteor.publish("adminUsers", function(){
   var result = [];
   if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ["admin"])) {
        result = Meteor.users.find();
   } else {
        this.stop();
        // YOUUU SHALL NOT.... PASS!!!  ~Gandalf
   }
   return result;
});
```

On client side, subscribe to this with:

```
Meteor.subscribe("adminUsers");
```

Don't do this. Omit it. `Meteor.users` is is your collection.

```
// NOO!! AllUsers = new Meteor.Collection("adminUsers");
```

Now I want to get all the Users in a Template with this code:

```
Template.adminUserverwaltung.helpers = {
    AllUsers: function(){
        return Meteor.users.find();
    }
};
```

and show the result in the template with this code:

```
<template name="adminUserverwaltung">
{{#each AllUsers}}
    {{this.username}}
{{/each}}
</template>
```

And it should now be working. :)

Comment: After years I now saw your answer, I like your code and your comments. It entertained me and makes me smile at work today 

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe("allUsers");
  Template.hello.users = function() {
    return Meteor.users.find();
  }
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.publish("allUsers", function(){
      var user = Meteor.user();
      if (user && user.emails[0].address === 'root@localhost'){
        return Meteor.users.find();
      }
      return null;
    });
  });
}
```

This way only user `root@localhost` will see all users. Other will only see themselves.

There's an example of custom users collection publication in the [meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users).

Comment: This seems to be discouraged by [meteor.com: Meteor.user()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user) documenting not to use `Meteor.user()` inside `Meteor.publish()`

Comment: It might have changed since 2013. [`publish`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) documentation suggests using `this.userId`.

Comment: Yes, I found I needed to collect the `_id`'s for the admins and populate a global array on the server-side for comparison to `this.userId`.  Trying to probe properties of the user records wasn't working for me inside publish.